# Jquery composite sparklines

Tags: jquery, composite, sparklines

I am new to sparklines and need help with something. I get data from mysql and populate a `span` tag with `class=sparks`. The graph is generated but when I create another `span` tag with the same class, but different data (composite line), I get the following message:

> Attempted to attach a composite sparkline to an element with no existing sparkline.

My JavaScript:

```
$(".sparks").sparkline( 'html', {
  composite:'true',
  type:'line',
  width:'900px',
  height:'400px',
  disableHiddenCheck:'true'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The second sparkline needs to be applied to the *same* span tag in order to work as a composite.

Sparklines will then draw onto the existing canvas element that it creates within the initial span.

Comment: can you give us an example?

Comment: @oki-erie-rinaldi Here is a jsfiddle with an example: https://jsfiddle.net/mattkibbler/c7kLhLko/3

As you can see, I save a reference to the initial element that `sparklines` is applied to and then apply the composite chart to the same element.

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid making a selection on the class. It's better to draw one, and then on the next ones you set the flag `composite` equal to *true*. And be sure that all the drawings are pointing to the same div.

Following this note, remember to set `changeRangeMin` and `chartRangeMax`
having the same values.

> Note: You'll usually want to lock the axis on both charts using
>   chartRangeMin and chartRangeMax if you want the same value on each
>   chart to occupy the same point.

A working example: https://jsfiddle.net/sLphjqoc/2/

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to create a compositeline and use the following code:

The value of Data below is = [10,10,10,10,4,3,2,2,5,6,7,4,1,5,7,9,9,1,1,1]

HTML & JavaScript:

```
$('#btn_refresh_memory').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/getSampleData',
        dataType: 'json',
        aysync: true,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#sparkline_view').sparkline(data, 
                  {type: 'line', composite: true, fillColor: false, 
                   lineColor: 'green',
                   changeRangeMin: 0, chartRangeMax: 10,
                   lineWidth:3, lineColor: '#008080',
                   disableHiddenCheck:'true',
                   height: '75px', width: '350px', tooltipSuffix: 'Cycles'});
        }
    });
});
```